# How to Deal with a KeyError Given by an API - Discord.py

Tags: python, api, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to use the *TGRCode* API to make a Discord command which returns information about a level in Super Mario Maker 2. However, I'm running into a problem.

If the level has no, for example, Clear Condition, then it throws a Key Error and stops the command. I know what it does that, because it just isn't present in the JSON that the API returns, and not as a empty string or anything.

However, the problem is that I am not sure how to deal with it.

(I am trying to receive the information using *AIOHTTP*)

I have tried using

```py
if clear_condition == None:
  clear_condition = "None"
```

That just returns a KeyError
I have also tried

```py
if clear_condition_name not in response:
  clear_condition_name = "None"
```

That just returns an error saying `ClientResponse` is not iterable.

I tried (with and without the quotation marks)

```py
if "clear_condition_name" not in response.json():
  clear_condition_name = "None"
```

And that just spits out another Key Error.

I have also checked [this article by Career Karma](https://careerkarma.com/blog/python-keyerror/#:%7E:text=A%20KeyError%20is%20raised%20when,to%20handle%20a%20key%20error.), but it does not help as I am not the one defining the dictionary.

Here is my current code:

```py
@commands.command()
  async def smm2_lookup_level(self, ctx, code):
    await ctx.reply(f"Getting level information of level with code `{code}`")
    print(f"{ctx.author.name} has requested to get all information for {code}.")

    MAIN = f"https://tgrcode.com/mm2/level_info/{code}"


    async with request("GET", MAIN, headers={}) as response:
      if response.status == 200:
        print("The TGRCode API returned OK; getting info...")
        data = await response.json()
        title = data["name"]
        description = data["description"]
        upload_date = data["uploaded_pretty"]
        course_id = data["course_id"]
        style = data["game_style_name"]
        theme = data["theme_name"]
        difficulty = data["difficulty_name"]
        tags = data["tags_name"]
        upload_time = data["upload_time_pretty"]
        number_of_comments = data["num_comments"]
        clear_condition_name = data["clear_condition_name"]
        clear_condition_magnitude = data["clear_condition_magnitude"]
        clears = data["clears"]
        attempts = data["attempts"]
        clear_rate = data["clear_rate"]
        plays = data["plays"]
        likes = data["likes"]
        boos = data["boos"]
        thumbnail = f"https://tgrcode.com/mm2/level_thumbnail/{code}"
        map = f"https://tgrcode.com/mm2/level_entire_thumbnail/{code}"

        if clear_condition_name not in response.json():
          clear_condition_name = "None"
          clear_condition_magnitude = ""

        if "clear_condition_magnitude" not in response.json():
          clear_condition_name = "None"
          clear_condition_magnitude = ""
        
        if "description" not in response.json():
          description = ""

        if "tags" not in response.json():
          tags = "None"
        

        embed = discord.Embed(title="SMM2 Level Information.")
        embed.add_field(name="Level Name", value=title, inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="Level Description", value=description, inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="Level Code", value=course_id, inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="Level Style", value=style, inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="Level Theme", value=theme, inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="Level Difficulty", value=difficulty, inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="Tags", value=tags, inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="Upload Date", value=upload_date, inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="Time taken to Clearcheck Course", value=upload_time, inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="Clear Condition Information", value=f"{clear_condition_name} {clear_condition_magnitude}.", inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="Clear Information", value=f"Clears: {clears}\nAttemps: {attempts}\nPlays: {plays}\nClear Rate: {clear_rate}.")
        embed.add_field(name="Number of Comments", value=number_of_comments, inline=True)
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=thumbnail)
        embed.set_image(url=map)
        embed.add_field(name="Like:Boo Ratio", value=f"{likes}:{boos}")

        await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} Here's the information for level with code `{code}`:", embed=embed)

      else:
        await ctx.send(f"I was unable to retrieve the information. Try again, if not the TGRCode API may be down, or there is an error on my end.\n*Response Status: {response.status}*")
        print(f"I was unable to retrieve the information from TGRCode.\n*Response Status: {response.status}*")
```

So, with all of what I have tried resulting in no help, I'm hoping I can find some here.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to read that key when you declare the `clear_condition_name` variable. You should check if the response data dictionary has such a key, like this:

```
clear_condition_name = data["clear_condition_name"] if "clear_condition_name" in data.keys() else "None"
```

Comment: The top method gives me another Key Error (`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: KeyError: 'clear_condition_name'`), however, **the bottom method does indeed work**. Thanks; I'll mark the question as Accepted because one of the two methods worked.

Comment: I removed it because it just checked for the key not existing. If you didn't remove the old declaration, it would still throw the key error. Anyway glad you got it sorted.